# Starting all files listed in a file list (Windows Batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I was wondering if you can, in Windows Batch, run all of the programs listed inside of a .txt file. For example, If I had a text file with 3 different files like so:

```
Example1.txt
Example2.txt
Example3.txt
```

is it possible to run all 3 of those programs at once based on the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "file_with_programs=c:\some.txt"

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%file_with_programs%") do (
    start "" "%%~#"
)

endlocal
```

Not sure this is what you want as the list there text files but not programs.Change the path to your file.

Comment: If the answer pleases you can accept it and both of us will receive some points.